# Error in rbind.na(row1, row2) : could not find function "rbind.na"

Tags: r

what is the package for `rbind.na`?

I have a simple code like:

```
row1 <- c("a","b","c","d")
row2 <- c("A", "B", "C")
row3 <- rbind.na(row1, row2)
```

But it complains with:

```
Error in rbind.na(row1, row2) : could not find function "rbind.na"
```

So, what is the package for `rbind.na()`?

Comment: [search on R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=rbind.na&latest=). Package canceR.

Comment: @phiver yes, but my RStudio cannot install such package.

Comment: Reading a bit more on the info provided it is a [bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/) package. more [info here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/canceR.html). check bioconductor on how to install their packages.

Comment: Rstudio has nothing to do with it, it's "just" a wrapper around R. In case you're using rstudio in your searches, you should probably search for terms using "r", instead.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution that does not require any package:

```
row1 <- c("a","b","c","d")
row2 <- c("A", "B", "C")
length(row2) <- length(row1)
row3 <- rbind(row1, row2)
```

Alternatively, check out `dplyr::bind_rows()`.